# Passwordless ssh from a webserver

Tags: ssh, lampp

I have an virtual Ubuntu machine (13.04) which i can currently use to ssh to a virtual OpenWrt machine. It works no problem with passwordless SSH because I set up the keys.

Also on the Ubuntu machine is a web server (XAMPP/LAMPP package that uses Apache) from which I have a PHP page that runs the SSH script on the command line using `shell_exec()`.

But the webserver does not have the same permissions as the Ubuntu user, as when I run the script from the webserver, it asks for the password (in a pop up box).

Is there anyway that I can create a key for the webserver in the same way that I have for the Ubuntu machine?

I've looked for an Apache user that I can use in the command line, but as far as I can tell, Apache uses a daemon (of which I have basically no understanding).

Is this possible?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible. easiest way is probably like this

- in ubuntu generate a new key as any user (ssh-keygen)
- register the key on the openwrt server
- check that the key works
- in ubuntu move the key to a sensible location (`/var/www` if it is *NOT* used as docroot, or something under `/etc/` or `/srv`) and chown it to the apache user (`www-data` probably)
- in `shell_exec` use `ssh -i $KEYFILE` when connecting